# Javascript page animation scrollTo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate

I'm looking for some advice on how to animate a page. I'm doing some sort of a full page slider but I would also like to scroll down to other divs when the nav links are clicked. I currently have it working for "Home" but it is scrolling the whole page and the nav bar disappears (I would like this to stay fixed).
Also, I would like these divs hidden until they are called by the .click function.

Here is the scrollTo JS:

```
$(function() {
// when you click the link w/ a id of home'
 $('#home').click(function() {
    // scroll to the DIV w/ an ID of 'homeDiv'
    $.scrollTo( '#homeDiv', 800, {easing:'swing'} );
 });
});
```

Complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hvYzm/3/
The scrollTo  library isn't linked up in the jsFiddle.

Any advice  greatly appreciated. I'm a newb to this so i'm sure a lot of this stuff can be done in a better way :)

Comment: you should use `$(this).scrollTo(..)` or any other selector not just `$.scrollTo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav bar needs to have a fixed position if you want it to move as you scroll:

```
nav {
    padding-left: 16%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    background: transparent;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZLt7/

Comment: That works but breaks the page also. The div slider gets pushed up and covers the nav.

Comment: Yeah, you need to put a placeholder element there to occupy the same amount of space.

Comment: making #full-slider fixed pushed the divs down but the slide panel and divs that are being scrolled to are ontop of the nav. Any advice?

Comment: Perfect, that works! Thanks. next question. It makes sense that the scroll is occurring behind the nav, and that you can see it. But, how do i make the top of the div im scrolling to stop at the bottom of the nav? Is that done by setting the final position of the scroll? Not sure how to do that

Comment: @Anthony If there is more content at the bottom the scrolling will stop with the target at the top of the page. This can be adjusted by passing an offset option to `scrollTo`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qu4jy/